# Arrows and color in matrix

Tags: matrices

Can someone help me in typing the following matrix in latex? All my efforts have failed. I don't want to use a tikz package, but want to write the matrix explicitly and include the arrows and colors. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: If you have the image and don't want to type it, include it as image.

Comment: please, show us what you try so far! and, what is wrong to write `matrix` in tikz?  in it is very simply to annotate matrix's parts and draw arrows.